# ASP.Net Core MVC Repository Pattern Unexpectedly disposing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I try to add a comment, I get the following error:

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

When the code runs the second line:

```
m_context.Comments.Add(comment);
m_context.SaveChanges();
```

Why is the context being disposed? If move the the TryAddComment method into the controller, it doesn't call Dispose early.

Here is what my Controller and Repository class look like (simplified).

CommentsController.cs:

```
public class CommentsController : Controller
{

    private ICommentRepository m_commentRepository;

    public CommentsController(ICommentRepository commentRepository)
    {
        m_commentRepository = commentRepository;
    }

    // POST: api/Comments
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostComment([FromBody] CommentAddViewModel commentVM)
    {
        Comment comment = new Comment
        {
            ApplicationUserId = User.GetUserId(),
            PostId = commentVM.PostId,
            Text = commentVM.Text
        };

        bool didAdd = m_commentRepository.TryAddComment(comment);

        if (!didAdd)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetComment", new { id = comment.CommentId }, comment);
    }

}
```

CommentRepository.cs:

```
public class CommentRepository : ICommentRepository, IDisposable
{

    public ApplicationDbContext m_context;

    public CommentRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        m_context = context;
    }
    public bool TryAddComment(Comment comment)
    {
        m_context.Comments.Add(comment);
        m_context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                m_context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Edit:

If I use a local CommentRepository, it works as expected. For example:

```
    CommentRepository localCommentRepo = new CommentRepository(m_context);
    bool didAdd = localCommentRepo.TryAddComment(comment);
```

Edit2:

In Startup.cs, I registered the IcommentRepository as Scoped and works as expected. Originally it was Singleton. Why would a singleton cause this issue?

```
services.AddSingleton<ICommentRepository, CommentRepository>(); //breaks
services.AddScoped<ICommentRepository, CommentRepository>(); //works
```

Edit3:

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show the service registrations

Comment: Added the service registrations

Comment: Can we see the ApplicationDbContext class definition? Because there could be a chance that it implements Dispose method, so the Add() method itself destroys the context object at the end.

Comment: I would guess that `ApplicationDbContext` is registered `Scoped` rather than `Singleton` and thus you have an issue where a dependency has a shorter lifetime than the item depending.

Comment: Added the definition.

Comment: I am not 100% sure. But my guess is, you have to make your ApplicationDbContext class that implements IDisposable interface and make the CommentRepository class not implementing the IDisposable. Otherwise you have to have an another layer called ServiceLayer or GenericRepository class that takes the DbContext and DbSet objects and implements IDisposable too. Here in your code the line m_context.Comments.Add(comment); ends by disposing the DbContext object. So the next line which saves it, does not have the DbContext object alive.

Comment: Along with @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment: where is the registration for `ApplicationDbContext`? It is `ApplicationDbContext` that needs the scoped lifestyle. The container creates `ApplicationDbContext` and should also be responsible for disposing it. The repository does not need to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Your comment helped me to understand what was going on.  Can't find documentation to see for sure, but yes the `ApplicationDbContext` seems to have a scoped lifetime.  @qujck why does the repository not need to implement `IDisposable`? Every guide I read mentions it should.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither your repository nor your `DbContext` should be singletons. The correct way to register them is `services.AddScoped` or `services.AddTransient`, as a `DbContext` shouldn't live longer than a request and the `AddScoped` is exactly for this.

`AddScoped` will return the same instance of a `DbContext` (and repository if you register it as such) for the lifetime of the scope (which in ASP.NET Core equals the lifetime of a request).

When you use `AddScope` you shouldn't dispose the context yourself, because the next object that resolves your repository will have an disposed context.

Entity Framework by default registers the context as scoped, so your repository should be either scoped (same lifetime as the context and request) or transient (each service instance gets it's own instance of the repository, but all repositories within a request still share the same context).

Making the context singleton causes serious issues, especially with the memory (the more you work on it, the more memory the context consumes, as it has to track more records). So a `DbContext` should be as short-lived as possible.

Duration of the context has the advantage that you can still roll back all operations during the request if something goes wrong and handle it as one single transaction.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped clear things up. Are you saying I should remove the `IDisposable` implementation from the repository because it will be disposed of properly already?

Also, when I was debugging, the debugger would step out of `TryAddComment` after the first call do the `DBContext` and it was the controller that was calling the Dispose method. Could you shed some light on why the controller would be calling `Dispose` before the request was completed?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the whole code. Are you using the `using` keyword somewhere? i.e. `using(context) { context.Add(...); }`? Or using multiple requests? If you fire two requests, one would call dispose on the repository (or the GC would do, when it collects it) and the other request would try to access the disposed context. Your intitial problem was, that the repository was singleton, where your context was not. So your first request would likely get the context and dispose it at the end. Your second request gets the singleton repository whose context is already disposed.

Comment: No I'm not using `using` anywhere. That's exactly what I was thinking, that a second request was the one calling `Dispose` which was disposing the Singleton Repository. I understand conceptually what's happening. But I still don't understand why a Singleton repository would behave this way. Wouldn't the `DBContext` always be disposed after the first request since initializing the application? [Here](https://github.com/dannycarrera/ASPCoreDILifeTimeTest) is a link to a test project that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: Well, after the first request, your repositories dispose is called (breakpoint). At this point, your repository holds a reference to an disposed context. next requests returns the same instance of repository, because its singleton. When trying to access the context, the exception is thrown

Comment: That makes sense to me, but if that is the case, why can you make consecutive calls to the GetComment successfully? Shouldn't they have a disposed context after the first request?