# Use DbContext in other .NET Class Library

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core with EF Core Code First.
I am defining the dependency injection of the DbContext in service configuration of the Startup.cs of my ASP.NET Core project like described here (https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopmentDatabase")));
    }
```

But I do not want to use the DbContext in a controller like described at the same site but I want to outsource it to another .NET Core Class Library project together with the Migration.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Abstract the dbcontext with an interface either directly or via repository pattern and call that from your controller

Answer (score 1):

Implement the **Repository Pattern**

It's explained clearly here: [Building Your First Web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html#add-a-repository-class)

But register your repository as:

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
```

instead of using `.AddSingleton` as the link suggests, to avoid [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545838/asp-net-core-mvc6-repository-pattern-unexpectedly-disposing).

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but I want to implement the repository class in an extra project (preferable a .NET Core Class Library). The description in your link explains how to do it in one single project.

Comment: It should be no difference to have it on other assembly as long as you register it in `ConfigureServices`...

Answer (score 0):

I just put my xxxDbContext in a dll library project, but decided to keep migrations in the asp project:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(b);
        b.UseSqlServer("Data Source=...", x => x.MigrationsAssembly("WebApp1"));
```

If you don't use `MigrationsAssembly`, your migrations should go to the dll I believe.

But I'm having problems using the dll in another project, I can't initiate a connection to the database